# How to capture image and video using react-native-camera-kit?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-camera

I don't know how to capture image using `react-native-camera-kit` and neither how to record video using it.
Please help!

I've tried this `const image = await this.camera.capture(true);` but it gives me an error - `java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap`

Comment: Me too on Oppo Device

Answer (score 0):

const image= await cameraRef.current.camera.capture();
//Use this